# Preference to show x number of questions when looking at own profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request

By default in Unix stackexchange as well as elsewhere, the default number of questions you can look into your profile or somebody else's profile is 50 per page. There should be a way to increase/make it variable so at a glance I can look at all my questions . For e.g. in my profile I have 150 odd questions

https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/50490/shirish?tab=questions

But I have to browse through 3 pages. It would be nice if I could set in my profile as to how many questions I would like to look at . Sometimes tags and keywords are just not enough and I need to hunt/browse through to see if I have not asked the question before.

[image: how it looks]

Comment: BTW: not sure if you're aware of this, but in the search box you can add `user:50490` to search only your stuff. That might help.

Comment: And if you go to a profile page, the appropriate `user:` filter is pre-entered in the search field.

Comment: If I could get all my Qs, or all my As in one list, I could use my browser's search to look for term without having to hit the server with a request for each term and page through results looking for the *one* I think I remember.